# MVC Persisting User Data within the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm rewriting a fairly small internal facing application in MVC and trying to figure out the best way to persist user data across the application.  In the Startup class I'm pulling the user name off the httpcontext, checking it against our SQL database, which then returns the populated user object.  Since I'm starting from the ground up here I'd like to implement a credible, but not super complicated solution for being able to pass that object around the application.  My research so far elicits just putting it in a session or tempData, which seems kind of hacky, to implementing ASP Identity which seems a bit much.  Any suggestions on something that works but is still somewhat legit?

Comment: Putting the object in `HttpContext.Current.Session` is perfectly legit.

Comment: From the top of my head I don't think temp data stays around long, maybe just for the request? But session is certainly a good fit for your requirement

Comment: As long as you have Sessions enabled... SessionData is essentially the same as a Cache with your SessionId as the key.

Comment: But you might also look at JWT tokens, for when the MVC moves to SPA.

Comment: Spoke with another developer in the company and he said session would work too, mainly because we won't have that many users altogether much less at the same time.  Thanks to everyone that weighed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with using Session... That's what it's there for. However, I would implement a helper class to handle it for you and abstract it away as personally I don't like calls directly to session objects bleeding into my code and it makes it easy if you want to migrate it elsewhere at a later date. So something like:

```
public static class UserHelper
{
  public static void SetUser(User user)
  {
    HttpContext.Current.Session["user"]= user;
  }

  public static User GetCurrentUser()
  {
   return (User)HttpContext.Current.Session["user"];
  }
}
```